# Reflect GitLab repo changes in VSTS code

Tags: gitlab, azure-devops

I have a repository in GitLab that is used by our development team. On the other hand, there is a VSTS setup (at xyz.visualstudio.com) that we use to manage our scrum board.

As of today, we have to manually import the repository in VSTS every time a feature is finalized. Once the repository is imported, it does not pull the latest commits by itself.

How do I ensure that every time a developer commits code to GitLab repository, same is displayed in VSTS automatically? Am I missing something when I use "import repository" feature in VSTS?

Comment: I think the thing you want is a gitlab runner https://docs.gitlab.com/runner. They execute every time new code is pushed to the repo, you can configure them to do anything you want.

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Comment: Hi. I was not able to solve this issue. We ended up just creating a pipeline to check in code to VSTS from Git.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html#pushing-to-a-remote-repository to push everything into a repository in VSTS, easily done via access token with the right permissions.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a repository in GitLab that is used by our development team. On
>   the other hand, there is a VSTS setup (at xyz.visualstudio.com) that
>   we use to manage our scrum board.

First impression is that you should either choose one repository or check the API of both products to investigate whether the tools could be integrated. From a DevOps perspective, repetitive processes like this that are done manually over and over again should be automated.